# Select all checkbox of interactive grid only selects the rows that have already been rendered?

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-apps, oracleapplications

I have long list of rows in interactive grid. As I scroll down, the grid loads more rows. The select all checkbox on top only selects the rows that have been rendered in the view. Is there a way to select rows that have not been rendered yet? or Is there an event that gets fired when loading is complete?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no event that occurs when the last page of results is loaded.

You can detect if the last page has been loaded using this undocumented / unsupported method:

```
var g = apex.region("emp").call("getViews","grid");
if (g.model._haveAllData) {
    // all the rows are now shown
}
```

To load an additional page of results:

```
g.view$.grid("lastPage");
```

*Note: don't do what I did and try to put these in a simple Javascript loop - this fails because the loop wouldn't wait until each page is loaded before trying to load another.*

An approach I might take if the number of records is expected to be <1000, is to change the pagination to Page, and the number of records per page to 1000. That way you know they'll all be loaded initially.